# How can I log out of Ask Different?

Tags: support, login

How can I log out of Ask Different?

Answer (score 4):

See [How to log out of a Stack Exchange site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222556/how-to-log-out-of-a-stack-exchange-site).

Basically click on the StackExchange logo on top right and select "log out".

[image]